# AngularJS Filter records for corresponding value in a field (array) in record

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-filter

So I am a newbie on AngularJS and I've been trying to get some sort of answer for this but no luck, hence this post.

I have an array of objects (JSON), and in a single object, there is a field called categories, this field is actually an array itself and can hold multiple values.

The filter that I'm looking for is, there is a "select" and user will pick a "select" value and all the records having that value in their categories array should appear to the user and rest can be hidden. This "select" has multiple selection but I'm considering to keep it to single selection. But since I want to deliver the best product, I would really appreciate if you can help me out for both multiple and single select.

Here is the sample data:

> var jobs = [{"ID":"10","Title":"SQA
> Engineer","Employer":"XXXX","Address":"XXX
> Floor","Email":"XXXX","ContactNumber":"","Description":"1 year
> experience.","Qualification":"XXXX","LastApplyDate":"2016-08-26","Type":"1","CreatedDT":"2016-08-06
> 13:06:36","CreatedBy":null,"Categories":["25","28"]},{"ID":"8","Title":"Maid","Employer":"XXX","Address":"XXX","Email":"XXXX","ContactNumber":"XXXX","Description":"","Qualification":"NONE","LastApplyDate":"2016-08-26","Type":"1","CreatedDT":"2016-08-06
> 12:27:17","CreatedBy":null,"Categories":["28"]}];

Comment: Angular has some pretty good built-in filtering capabilities and decent documentation on how to implement said filters. Check out the docs and let me know if you have any questions https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Ive visited this but I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: I'll mock up a demo real fast so you can see how it works

Comment: Thanks looking forward to it

Comment: Okay. Let me know if this is what you were looking for: http://jsbin.com/cefojefebo/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Yup that seems to be it, but what if i have multiple values selected, like say 28 and 25 and i want the all records having either or both of them

Comment: Working on that as we speak =)

Comment: Great, please post that as an answer, so i can select it as best answer

Comment: Done. Let me know what you think!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so there are two different approaches here. One is very simple, just using the basic, [built-in angularjs `filter` api](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), and the other is done by creating our own custom filter.

#### First (easy) approach

Single value selector for job categories, returns all jobs that contain a match for the selected category.

**Edit - Updated code & demo based on comments! [Working DEMO](http://jsbin.com/gunujeleca/edit?html,js,output)**

```
<label>Category: 
    <select ng-model="category" ng-options="category.id as category.name for category in categories"></select>
</label>
<div class="results">
    <div class="job-listing" 
         ng-bind="job | json"
         ng-repeat="job in jobs | filter:{Categories: category}:true">
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Second (more advanced) approach

Multiple value selector for job categories, returns all jobs that contain a match for **ALL** selected categories. *(i.e. a job with categories ["25"] will return false if "25" and "26" are selected)*

**[Working DEMO](http://jsbin.com/temocogegi/1/edit?html,js,output)**

Here we have to create a custom filter, because, although angular's built-in filter does a lot of great stuff, it has its limitations.

**Our custom filter (match ALL search terms)**

```
app.filter("getMatches", function () {
  return function (items, options) {
    var options = options || {};
    var searchField = options.searchField || "";
    var searchTerms = options.searchTerms || [];
    if (searchField === "" || !searchTerms.length || (searchTerms.length === 1 && searchTerms[0] === '')) {
      return items;
    }
    return items.filter(function (item) {
      return !searchTerms.some(function(term) {
        return item[searchField].indexOf(term) === -1;
      });
    });
  }
});
```

**Modified filter (match ANY search term)**

```
app.filter("getMatches", function () {
  return function (items, options) {
    var options = options || {};
    var searchField = options.searchField || "";
    var searchTerms = options.searchTerms || [];
    if (searchField === "" || !searchTerms.length || (searchTerms.length === 1 && searchTerms[0] === '')) {
      return items;
    }
    return items.filter(function (item) {
      return searchTerms.some(function(term) { // notice the subtle difference here
        return item[searchField].indexOf(term) > -1; // and here
      });
    });
  }
});
```

**Supporting HTML**

```
<select multiple ng-model="selectedCategories" ng-options="category for category in categories"></select>

<div class="job-listing" ng-bind="job | json"
     ng-repeat="job in jobs | getMatches:{searchField: 'Categories', searchTerms: selectedCategories}">
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried to implemented the easy approach, but I've ran into some problems:

1. The category select drop-down needs to have names instead of numbers.
2. Some jobs may not have any category selected, and they should list out when null option is selected.

Comment: Also, I have an array to fill up the drop-down so no need to fill by acquiring the categories first

Comment: @NasirDevlani Okay, this should have been easy enough for you to figure out, but I'm bored so I wrote your code for you, but don't get used to that. See my edits on the easy approach to address your 3 problems